Space Difference for One-Character Elements: List<Character> vs List<String>
not sure if I am asking this correctly, but does anyone know if List<Character> and List<String> would hold different amount of memory space for one-character elements, that is, character elements or strings with only one character each?
I would expect List<Character> to hold less memory space but since Character is a class and not the primitive char, I wonder if List<Character> would then hold the same or different amount of space as List<String>.

@Hulk I see! That actually makes sense! Thank you!

Use whatever makes your code more readable and/or easiest to work with.

The List istself only contains references in both cases, so it is the same size.
This does not mean that there will not be any effect on overall memory one way or the other, but this will depend on the rest of your application.
The values might already exist in memory anyway, and depending on their values and how they are used elsewhere, caching may be involved. Strings might be interned, and frequent Characters can also be cached by the implementation, e.g. if they are created with valueOf():

This method will always cache values in the range '\u0000' to '\u007F', inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range..


There is no point in comparing them because they perform different functions.
A String can, for example, represent digraphs that a single Character cannot. Using Strings to represent singular characters is confusing, because whoever sees a string assumes that it contains multiple characters. It introduces unnecessary error vectors because you have to ensure everywhere that no multi-character string ever enters the List.
So, if you only need to support data consisting of singular Charcters, then use List<Character>. If you are concerned of memory, then use a char[].
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize
